# Symfony 2 - FOSUserBundle, there is no access token?

Tags: php, security, symfony, access-token, fosuserbundle

I'm currently learning symfony 2 framework and I use FOSUserBundle for the management of my users. What I want to do is working with access token when user is connected. Is safer for the security. So when a user connects to the website, I should send him back an access_token, right ? Like =

```
access_token : sqbkktg3s00vzz7gg3s198rzb9g3s2me2u2ng3s3 ...
```

I thought that the framework symfony 2 does already that, or FOSUserBundle, but I couldn't find anything about that.

In the security context service of symfony 2, there is a method called getToken(). But it returns a TokenInterface object, I read what are methods of this object, I tried to use some of them, but it did nothing.

What is the best way for working with access tokens please? I'm sure there is a easy way, but I didn't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle).

FOSOAuthServerBundle was created for the same group that FOSUserBundle, and in its Documentation explain how to combine both bundles.

Check documentation and examples for FOSOAuthServerBundle:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

I hope I have helped!

Comment: Thanks, I will try to add this bundle, to configure it.
I'll let you know if I could make it. 
After reading documentations, it looks good.
Thanks for answering